# displaying Busy Indicator on a thread and launching the application : Threading error (The calling thread cannot access this object)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm developing a WPF application and following MVVM approach. I have to show the busy indicator on my log-in screen when an user click on the 'Enter' Button. On 'Enter' button I am having an ICommand named 'EnterCommand' which then check the authentication and then loads the MainWindow.

```
private ICommand _EnterCommand;
public ICommand EnterCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _EnterCommand ?? (_EnterCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
        {
            Thread objThread = new Thread(LoadApplication);
            objThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            objThread.Start();

        }));
    }
}
```

IsBusy propery is bound to this showprogress

```
private bool _ShowProgress = false;
public bool ShowProgress
{
    get { return _ShowProgress; }
    set
    {
        if (_ShowProgress != value)
        {
            _ShowProgress = value;
            FirePropertyChanged("ShowProgress");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm creating a thread on this command then setting the IsBusy property from (bool Property name : ShowProgress) MVVM.

in LoadApplication:

```
public void LoadApplication()
{
    ShowProgress= true;
    if (AuthenticateUser)
    {
        MainWindow objMainWindow = new MainWindow();
        objMainWindow.Show();
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
    }
    ShowProgress= false;
}
```

objMainWindow.Show() is throwing error that - The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Also in App.xaml I have set StartupUri as my 'Log-in' window.

This is able to show the Busy Indicator as soon as user clicks on the 'Enter' button however failed while showing the mainWindow.

Error message is "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

I have to show the busyindicator as long as my MainWindow (which is home screen) is not launched.

Any help to rectify this?

Comment: Which line throws the Error?

Comment: objMainWindow.Show();

Comment: Have you tried to do it with BeginInvoke?

Comment: i have not tried BeginInvoke. Can u suggest some sample code for this ?

Answer (score 0):

the exception is thrown because you cannot access UI element form a background thread.

you have to either call the `objMainWindow.Show()` from main/UI thread or ask the dispatcher to call it for you

if you have to call it from the backgorund thread you can do it like this:

```
Action act = () =>
{
   MainWindow objMainWindow = new MainWindow();
   objMainWindow.Show();
  Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
};

 System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(act);
```

I would recomend reading the following  [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)

Comment: how to use dispatcher in this case ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this but now it does show the BusyIndicator and application is being launched.

Comment: sorry for typo error. It does not show the the BusyIndicator and application is getting launched withot displaying the busy indicator.

Comment: @user2519971 this is actually another question ;) post your XAML for the busyIndicator...

Comment: <wpfx:BusyIndicator Name="BusyBar" IsBusy="{Binding ShowProgress}"  >
            <wpfx:BusyIndicator.BusyContent>
                <Button Name="BusyButton" Height="150" Width="435" 
                          Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                        Background="Blue" 
                Foreground="White" Content="Application is Busy!" />
            </wpfx:BusyIndicator.BusyContent>
        </wpfx:BusyIndicator>

Comment: @user2519971 it seems that you didnt set the window/BusyIndicator dataContext right this is why the binding doesnt work, you can look for binding error at run time or use snoop

Comment: Thanks but data context is right because it shows the busy indicator as soon as execution reaches to the public void LoadApplication() method where I am setting ShowProgress= true; but throes error on objMainWindow.Show(); (pls have a look on LoadApplication method code posted in the begining.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code :

```
private void AsyncCallback(IAsyncResult result){
    var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        MainWindow objMainWindow = new MainWindow();
        objMainWindow.Show();
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
public void LoadApplication()
    {
        ShowProgress= true;
        if (AuthenticateUser)
        {
            var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
            dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                MainWindow objMainWindow = new MainWindow();
                objMainWindow.Show();
                Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
            }
        }
        ShowProgress= false;
    }
```

Comment: can u tell how to call AsyncCallback from my ICommand EnterCommand? I tried AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(AsyncCallback); but its not loading the application .

Comment: In the your command you call LoadApplication? If so then you have just to replace the 'if (_ShowProgress != value)' with the sample above. I have forgotten to enter the third line.

Comment: I am lost on this. do i need to put this in  ShowProgress ? Can u suggest which one to keep where ? It wud be a great help for me.         set
            {
                AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(AsyncCallback);
            }

Comment: Your error was when you said 'objMainWindow.Show();'. Wasn;t it?? Or the progress is a second question??

Comment: yes objMainWindow.Show(); is throwing error. I want to fix this only. Progress bar is not a concern. Any thought on this ?